# If $f$ is differentiable on I=[a,b], and $f$ is decreasing, then for all $x\in I$ $f'(x) \leq 0$ Is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove that If $f$ is differentiable on I=[a,b], and $f$ is decreasing, then for all $x\in I$ $f'(x) \leq 0$.

Let $c\in I$ and let $x\in I$ where $x<c$, since $f$ is decreasing in $I$, then $$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\leq0,$$ therefore $$\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\leq0.$$ Similarly, for $x\in I$ where $x>c$, we have $$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\leq0.$$ Therefore $$0\geq f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.$$
Since $c$ is arbitrary in $I$, then for all $x\in I$, $f'(x)\leq0$. Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need consider both left-sided and right-sided limit. Existence of the limit implies that one-sided limit coincides with the limit. But, your proof is right.

Comment: For x=0 or x=1 you have only the right-side or left-side derivative. See Jeon"s comment above.

Comment: I see, it's because we can write: for every $x\in I$ $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\leq 0$?